# Bypass a template error with a private destructor

Tags: c++, templates

In compile time, I've got the following issue, how to make this compile, because conceptually for me it's correct, any suggestions of refactoring are welcome.

I got a compile error because "Search" destructor is private but I won't use delete on a Search pointer since I provided a custom Deleter in the initialization of the base class. I know that the compiler doesn't know that, how to bypass it.

error description :
error C2248: cannot access private member declared in class 'Search'
compiler has generated 'Search::~Search' here

```
class Search
{
public:
static Search* New(/* */);    // using a pool of already allocated objects to avoid expensive allocations
    static void Delete(Search*);

private:
    Search(/* */) {/* */}
    ~Search() {/* */}
};


template<class T>
class MyList
{
    public:
    typedef (*CustomDeleter) (T* pElement);

    MyList(CustomDeleter lpfnDeleter = NULL) {};


    void Empty()
    {
        for (/**/)
         {
            if (m_pList[m_nListLastUsed])
            {
               if (m_lpfnCustomDeleter == NULL)
                  delete m_pList[m_nListLastUsed]; // COMPILE ERROR HERE BECAUSE Search destructor is private BUT I won't use that instruction since
                                                    // I provided a custom Deletern I know that the compiler doesn't know that, how to bypass it
               else
                  m_lpfnCustomDeleter(m_pList[m_nListLastUsed]);
            }
         }
    }

    private:
    T** m_pList;
    CustomDeleter m_lpfnCustomDeleter;  // Pointer to a custom deleter
};

class Query : public MyList<Search>
{
    public:
    Query() : MyList<Search>(&Search::Delete) // I set a custom deleter since Search hides its destructor : is this the right way ?
    {}

    ~Query()
    {
        /****/
        Empty(); // PROBLEM HERE
        /***/
    }
};
```

Comment: @Holt because, I don't want to delete Search objects, I want to store them in lock free stack (after cleaning them) in order to be used later with New

Comment: Just because you don't think you'll *call* the code doesn't mean *invalid* code can still exist. `delete m_pList[m_nListLastUsed]; ` expects a properly accessible destructor, which you've not provided. Thus the code is not valid, thus your error. I'd have to gel on it for a moment to consider whether this has possible sfinae alternatives.

Comment: `m_pList` is not defined anywhere. Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that 'm_lpfnCustomDeleter' is never NULL or better nullptr. You can make sure of this by falling back to a default 'deleter' if the user does not provide with any custom deleter.

I would prefer something like below.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename PointerType>
struct DefaultDeleter {
  void operator()(PointerType* ptr) {
    std::cout << "Delete\n";
  }
};

struct CustomDeleter {
  void operator()(int* ptr) {
    std::cout << "Custom int deleter" << std::endl;
  }
};

template <typename T, typename Deleter = DefaultDeleter<T>>
class Whatever
{
public:
  Whatever() {
    std::cout << "Cons\n";
  }
  void deinit() {
    Deleter d;
    auto v = new T;
    d(v); // Just for the sake of example
  }
};

int main() {
  Whatever<char> w;
  w.deinit();

  Whatever<int, CustomDeleter> w2;
  w2.deinit();
  return 0;
}
```

**Updated :: W/o code refactoring**
Assuming w/o c++11

1. Have this small metaprogram added to your code base.

   namespace my {

   ```
         template <typename T, typename U> struct is_same {
           static const bool value = false;
         };

         template <typename T>
         struct is_same<T, T> {
           static const bool value = true;
         };

         template <bool v, typename T = void> struct enable_if;

         template <typename T = void> struct<true, T> {
           typedef T type;
         };  

       }
   ```
2. Change your Empty function to:

   void Empty() {
     for (/****/) {
       do_delete();
     }
   }

```
    template <typename =
                  typename my::enable_if<my::is_same<T, Search>::value>::type>
    void do_delete() {
      assert (m_lpfnCustomDeleter != NULL);
      m_lpfnCustomDeleter(m_pList[m_nListLastUsed]);
    }

    void do_delete() {
      delete m_pList[m_nListLastUsed];
    }
```

If you are using c++11, the you dont have to write the metaprogram under namespace 'my'. Just replace 'my::is_same' and 'my::enable_if' with 'std::is_same' and 'std::enable_if'.

Note:, Have not compiled and tested the above code.

Comment: The CustomDeleter is a feature I added to "MyList" so I used the NULL default value to avoid refactoring the old code using MyList without that parameter.

Comment: If you can, then you should consider refactoring the design of the code. Something does not feel right about it. Can you tell me what is 'm_pList' ? If it is holding a pointer to 'Search' the you just cannot delete it and make its destructor as private. Or you do something similar to what I have shown and make 'CustomDeleter' as friend of Search.

Comment: Apparently your solution is neat... I will try this... Otherwise, MyList is a sorted list used by other classes too... but the other classes have public destructors. Is it clear now ?

Comment: Do you enable c++11 while building ?

Comment: Your default deleter doesn't delete ;) Also OP can directly pass `&Search::Delete` as the template parameter, without the need to create an additional structure.

Comment: @coyotte508 Yeah, I am bit too lazy :). The deleter struct is actually the prefered method. You can look how unique_ptr and shared_ptr takes a deleter. This enables us to do a lot of type checking using traits to make sure that we are handling the right types.

Comment: @Arunmu `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` can both take either a structure or a function as the second template parameter. What I meant is that OP can use your code like this: `Whatever<int, &Search::Deleter> w2;`, without changing the `Whatever` class. There's no benefit for him of writing the whole structure code to create a functor.

Comment: @coyotte508: Ah..I get your point. Yes, you are right, OP can pass the deleting function directly.

Comment: @Arunmu Thank you it solved my problem, I made some optimizations though : I made the Deleter functor a member of the class, and in the operator(), I pass a reference to the pointer PointerType*&

Comment: @Aminos Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Separate the code doing the deleting from the rest:

```
        if (m_pList[m_nListLastUsed])
        {
           if (m_lpfnCustomDeleter == NULL)
              delete m_pList[m_nListLastUsed]; // COMPILE ERROR HERE BECAUSE Search destructor is private BUT I won't use that instruction since
                                                // I provided a custom Deletern I know that the compiler doesn't know that, how to bypass it
           else
              m_lpfnCustomDeleter(m_pList[m_nListLastUsed]);
        }
```

Replace the code above by a call to:

```
custom_delete(m_pList[m_nListLastUsed]);
```

Then add it as a method of your list class, don't forget to include `<type_traits>` as well:

```
std::enabled_if<std::is_destructible<T>::value, void>::type custom_delete(T* ptr) {
    /* Note: this isn't pre-2000 anymore, 'lpfn' as a prefix is horrible,
       don't use prefixes! */
    if (m_lpfnCustomDeleter) {
       m_lpfnCustomDeleter(ptr);
    } else {
       delete ptr;
    }
}

std::enabled_if<!std::is_destructible<T>::value, void>::type custom_delete(T* ptr) {
     if (!m_lpfnCustomDeleter) {
          throw "No custom deleter for a non destructible type!";
     }
     m_lpfnCustomDeleter(ptr);
}
```

`enabled_if` will make it so that the function where it can `delete` the object directly doesn't exist in your list if the object has a private destructor.

Alternatively, you could pass a structure (or function) acting as a custom deleter as the second template argument of your list with a default value as one that calls the delete operator, then directly call this structure on your pointer, as in Arunmu's anser.